# Java Replace Questionmarks not surrounded by quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I'm replacing questionmarks in a string with different values.

Example:

```
String: "XYZ(?,?,?)"

Values: [1, 'Text', 0.5]

Result: XYZ(1,'Text', 0.5)
```

---

My Preudo-Code:

```
String s = "XYZ(?,?,?)";
for(int i = 0; i < array.lengh; i++){
   s = s.replaceFirst("\\?",array[i]);
}
```

---

Normally this works well. But sometimes I have a Question mark in the values like: Values: `[1,'Question?',0.5]`. Then my result is: `XYZ(1,'Question0.5', ?)`. This is because the function replaces the question mark of the text replaced one iteration earlier.

How can I tell the function to replace only question marks that are not surrounded by quotes? Whats the correct regex?

Comment: Should your pseudo-code be `s = s.replaceFirst(regex, replacement)`;?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have to use regex or replace, how about this?

```
String s = "XYZ(?,?,?)";
String[] tokens = s.split("\\?");
s = "";
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   s += tokens[i] + array[i];
}
s += tokens[array.length];
```

(edits: escape ? in regex, length has a t, need part after last insertion)

If there can be extra question-marks, that is more of then than the number of values to be inserted, and you want to keep the extra ones and any text after them as the OP code does, limit the `split`:

```
String[] tokens = s.split("\\?", array.length+1);
```

If the number of question-marks or the total size of the result (the template string plus the insertions) is large, repeated string concatenation performs badly; use `StringBuilder` instead:

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder (s.length()+estimated_expansion);
// this estimate doesn't have to be correct, but if it is high enough 
// without being *much* too high performance is optimized
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ){
  b.append(tokens[i]).append(array[i]);
}
s = b.append(tokens[array.length]).toString();
```

Comment: this will lead to the same problem, if any of the questionmaks is surrounded by a quote, so that doesn't solve the OP problem.

Comment: @chsdk no, it will not cause the same problem. This is a valid solution.

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir Ah yes you are right, my bad, I missed the point that the string will be splitted once, then it will be finely replaced.

Comment: @Utku it's valid as to not rescanning the questionmarks, but it had some minor bugs: JCheong: I edited 3 minor bugs and 2 possible enhancements; if you disagree please feel free to revert or re-edit.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for the greate code. Me too learned so much

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all question marks with `%s` first, then use `String.format(input, args...)`. Something like this:

```
Object[] array = {1, "Test", 0.5};
String s = "XYZ(?,?,?)";

String output = String.format(s.replace("?", "%s"), array);
System.out.println(output);
```

Will give you this output:

> XYZ(1,Test,0.5)

Also, notice that, in your question, your `s.replaceFirst("\\?",array[i]);` call is uneffective, because in Java strings are immutable and all operations on string, such as replace, return a new String, and you should use the returned one.

One other note: Strings should be in double quotes and not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
String regex = "\\?(?=[^']+$)";
```

The idea is when you call `s.replaceFirst(regex, str)`, the first `"?"` not to be followed by a quote cannot be inside quotes.

Answer (score 0):

How about a more straightforward approach as coded below?

```
public class Replacer {
    static String replace(String s, String[] values) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (c != '?')
                sb.append(c);
            else
                sb.append(values[j++]);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(replace("XYZ(?, ?, ?)", new String[]{"1", "Question?", "0.5"}));
        System.out.println(replace("XYZ(?, ?, ?)", new String[]{"foo", "bar", "baz"}));
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
XYZ(1, Question?, 0.5)
XYZ(foo, bar, baz)
```